# Setting up Jenkins with RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, jenkins

I am looking for advice on how to correctly setup Ruby/RVM for use with Jenkins. When running Jenkins builds it runs them as Jenkins and I would like to be able to run builds with things like

```
gem install gemName
```

Without getting a `you do not have permission to write to /Library/Ruby/Gems` for example.

Currently this folder is owned by `root wheel` which explains why Jenkins does not have permission.

What is the best way to set this up? Do I just change the permission on the folder?

I also find myself running builds with

```
withEnv(['PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH']) {
    sh '''npm install
          grunt build
          gem install gemName
       '''
  }
```

Which feels like a bit of a workaround to not setting up my environment correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is your not telling Jenkins what rvm gemset you want to use. You also need to set the she-bang.

````
withEnv(['PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH') {
    sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
          rvm use 2.3.3@gemset --create 
          npm install
          grunt build
          gem install bundler
          bundle install
       ```
}
````